# An array contains two objects, how can they be merged?

Tags: vue.js

```js
skills = [
  {skill_id: 1, skill_name: “IT”},
  {skill_id: 2, skill_name: “cooking”}
]
```

Desired output:
IT, Cooking

I have tried to use merge() to merge the two objects. However, I cannot seem to get the desired output.

Comment: @Rohìt Jíndal Yes, it does answer my qns. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` to transform array values like

```js
const values = skills.map(skill => skill.skill_name);
```